# UISplitViewController in landscape mode only and without nib

Tags: objective-c, ios4

can anyone explain to me how to setup the UI for a UISplitViewControll without using a nib and have it show in landscape more with both master and detail view?

---- RESOLVED ----

all i had to do was go into the info.plist and remove a few keys

```
<key>UIInterfaceOrientation</key> 
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
```

and it works

Answer (score 0):

Edit the info.plist and leave just the orientation you want to support. In my case just landscape left and right

```
<key>UIInterfaceOrientation</key>  
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string> 
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
```